Координаты метки в коллекции по щелчку
Никак не могу получить координаты метки, которая находится в коллекции, по щелчку мыши.
При событии dragEnd после перемещения метки все получается:
        myMap.geoObjects.events.add(['dragend'], function(e) 
    { 
        if (event.shiftKey)
        {
            var placemarkPosition = myMap.options.get('projection').fromGlobalPixels(
            myMap.converter.pageToGlobal(e.get('position')),
            myMap.getZoom()); 
            newCoords = placemarkPosition; 
            target = e.get('target'); 
            elId = target.properties.get('id');
        }
    });

А вот с обычным кликом по метке никак не удается справиться...

В общем, беда крылась совсем в другом месте.
Если кому интересно. Работает как на mouseDown так и на click
  function onMouseDown(e)
  {
        target = e.get('target');
            
        newCoords = placemarkPosition = myMap.options.get('projection').fromGlobalPixels(myMap.converter.pageToGlobal(e.get('position')), myMap.getZoom()); ;            
        elId = target.properties.get('id');
        myMap.events.remove('mousedown', onMouseDown);
        console.log(elId);
        console.log(newCoords);
  }

    myMap.geoObjects.events.add(['mousedown'], function(e) 
    { 
          onMouseDown(e);  
    });

